# 'PDOException' with message 'There is no active transaction'

Tags: zend-framework, pdo, transactions, zend-db

```
try{
    $zenddb->beginTransaction();
    $result = $zenddb->query($selectmembergroupdetail);

    $memberDetail = $result->fetchAll();
    if (count($memberDetail) <= 0) {
        throw new Exception('NO user found.');
    }
    /* calculation code here */


    $result = $zenddb->query($selectadmingroupdetail);
    /* calculation code here */

    $zenddb->insert('orders', $insertorder['orders']);
    $order_id = $zenddb->lastInsertId();

    foreach ($insertorderproduct as $insertorder_product) {
        $insertorder_product['orders_id'] = $order_id;
        $zenddb->insert('orders_products', $insertorder_product);
    }
    $zenddb->commit();
}catch(Exception $e){
    $zenddb->rollBack();
}
```

I have used this code for insert order in databse. This is mainly place order functionality. And for $zenddb I have used

```
$params = array(
  'host' => DB_SERVER,  
  'username' => DB_USERNAME,  
  'password' => DB_PASSWORD,  
  'dbname' => DB_DATABASE,  
  //'charset' => 'utf-8'
);
$zendb = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', $params);
```

When I execute the code I got Following error.

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'There is no active transaction' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myfeedly/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:322
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/myfeedly/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(322): PDO-&gt;rollBack()
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/myfeedly/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(524): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract-&gt;_rollBack()
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/myfeedly/public/web_service/webservice/orders.php(201): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract-&gt;rollBack()
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/myfeedly/public/web_service/client.php(58): WebService-&gt;placeOrder(Array)
#4 {main}
  thrown in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/myfeedly/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php</b> on line <b>322</b><br />
```

Can anybody point out where I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance :)